# docker: invalid reference format

Tags: node.js, docker

Im learning how to work with docker and my progress has been stopped by an error that I can't deal with.I've been looking for solutions on forums (including this site), but not one has helped me.
I would be very grateful if you could help me figure this out

Im trying to put this simple node.js code into docker and run it:

```
const express = require('express')

const app = express()

app.get('/:name', (req, res) => {
    const { name } = req.params

    res.json({ message: `Hello, ${name}!`})
})

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000
console.log(`Server is listening port ${PORT}`)
app.listen(PORT)
```

To run it with docker I used:

```
 docker run -it --name counter --rm -v %cd%:/app -w --env PORT=3002 -p 80:3002 /app node env /bin/bash
```

I've tried this both on Ubuntu and Windows and every time I get an error:

```
docker: invalid reference format: repository name must be lowercase.
See 'docker run --help'.
```

P.S. I hope that I wrote everything correctly and you understood me

Comment: It looks like `-w` is missing a path option, and there's a stray `/app` at the end; should these go together?  (I might remove that entirely in favor of your Dockerfile's `WORKDIR`, and also remove the `-v` option that hides the code you `COPY` into your image.)

Answer (score 0):

I will demo simple Docker image and run it.

This is my steps

### #1 Verify your `node.js` file

Your code name with `name-server.js`

```js
const express = require('express')

const app = express()

app.get('/:name', (req, res) => {
    const { name } = req.params

    res.json({ message: `Hello, ${name}!`})
})

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000
console.log(`Server is listening port ${PORT}`)
app.listen(PORT)
```

Install express library

```
npm install express
```

It will create `package.json`

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.18.2"
  }
}
```

### #2 Create Docker Image

Using a text editor or code editor,
add the following contents to the `Dockerfile:`

```
FROM node:lts-alpine

WORKDIR /usr/app

COPY package.json ./

RUN npm install

COPY . .

EXPOSE 3000

CMD ["node", "name-server.js"]
```

In your directory, should be display those files

[image]

Now build your own docker image

```
$ docker image build . -t name-server
```

If success, will be show this kind of message.

```
$ docker image build . -t name-server
Sending build context to Docker daemon  2.429MB
Step 1/7 : FROM node:lts-alpine
lts-alpine: Pulling from library/node
c158987b0551: Pull complete 
aabd449b9131: Pull complete 
756e97429a30: Pull complete 
1ee3f64a4fc8: Pull complete 
Digest: sha256:62a6ce21599b3183272e71527c9ce9fae9435195052d358f481eb3d69d3dc6f3
Status: Downloaded newer image for node:lts-alpine
 ---> 6d7b7852bcd3
Step 2/7 : WORKDIR /usr/app
 ---> Running in 38feeb18f0a7
Removing intermediate container 38feeb18f0a7
 ---> 503ef7080a31
Step 3/7 : COPY package.json ./
 ---> 765c8eb2e0b9
Step 4/7 : RUN npm install
 ---> Running in 8200fe976f7d

added 57 packages, and audited 58 packages in 9s

7 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

found 0 vulnerabilities
npm notice 
npm notice New major version of npm available! 8.19.2 -> 9.2.0
npm notice Changelog: <https://github.com/npm/cli/releases/tag/v9.2.0>
npm notice Run `npm install -g npm@9.2.0` to update!
npm notice 
Removing intermediate container 8200fe976f7d
 ---> 1db7dd859d61
Step 5/7 : COPY . .
 ---> 35f762f08c14
Step 6/7 : EXPOSE 3000
 ---> Running in 1f6b0c718e6b
Removing intermediate container 1f6b0c718e6b
 ---> 7229e441ff7a
Step 7/7 : CMD ["node", "name-server.js"]
 ---> Running in 91dee6b4102c
Removing intermediate container 91dee6b4102c
 ---> 8bf6b460803c
Successfully built 8bf6b460803c
Successfully tagged name-server:latest
```

And you can check your image by this commend

```
$ docker image ls
REPOSITORY                                             TAG          IMAGE ID       CREATED             SIZE
name-server                                            latest       8bf6b460803c   16 seconds ago      178MB
```

### #3 Run Docker Image

```
$ docker run -p 3000:3000 name-server
Server is listening port 3000
```

Open you browser and enter this URL
You can see express name server shows response.

```
http://localhost:3000/name/tom-cruise
```

[image]

more detail in here [Containerize an application](https://docs.docker.com/get-started/02_our_app/)